# How do I install usocket to my Raspberry Pi Pico modules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, esp8266, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Good Morning/Afternoon/Evening

I am trying to connect my Raspberry Pi Pico to a Realtime Database on Firebase. I'm using a Wave Pico-ESP8266 module to connect to wifi and micropython. I also have the ufirebase.py module that uses the usocket module, however I can't seem to get the module. I've tried downloading it from the package manager, the plug-ins manager, I've check the micropython forums, I've tried to find the modules files to manually install the package to the pico but no luck thusfar.

Does anyone know where I can find the usocket or am I missing something.
Kind Regards

Comment: The micropython socket module is a C module that relies on the hardware platform having network support. The Pico does not have network support. From looking at the product page, I think you'll need to communicate with the esp8266 module using the UART (serial connection).

Comment: There are examples [in the documentation](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Pico-ESP8266) that show how to communicate with this module.

Comment: You can of course just install micropython on an esp8266 or esp32, and then you have integrated socket support.

Answer (score 0):

in the `uf2 file` usocket is preinstalled so you probably have an older version of this file download a newest version using [this link](https://micropython.org/download/rp2-pico/)
or [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/micropython.html) (the second link has step by step how to download uf2 file)